# how to handle if a foreach loop in PS does not find the value? else does not work

Tags: powershell

i have a PS script that searches a csv for the computer name. it does that just fine, but i cannot seem to introduce anything to stop the script if it doesn't find it. I'm probably missing something, but I am new to PS scripting like this. i just need the script to exit if it doesn't find it.

```
#pull pc name
$computerid = (hostname)

#pull spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = Import-Csv -Path '\\<redacted>\software\Scripts\x2goScript\WorkstationList.csv'
ForEach ($row in $spreadsheet) { 
  if ($computerid -eq $spreadsheet.name) {
    $orange = $spreadsheet.OrangeID 
    $ipaddr = $spreadsheet.ServerIP
  }
}
```

Comment: You create a loop variable `$row` but inside your loop you use the array variable `$spreadsheet`.  ‍♂️ Actually you don't need a loop at all ... `if($computerid -in $spreadsheet.name)` should do the trick without a loop.  ‍♂️

Comment: it's still functionally the same lol. i did test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a test inside a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, I suggest finding the matching CSV row (object) using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) first, and then acting based on whether such a row was found or not:

```bash
$computerName = hostname

# Find the matching row for $computerName, if any.
$matchingRow = 
  Import-Csv -Path '\\<redacted>\software\Scripts\x2goScript\WorkstationList.csv' |
    Where-Object Name -eq $computerName

if (-not $matchingRow) { 
  Write-Warning "No CSV row found for server $computerName." 
  # Exit the script, for instance.
  exit 1
}

$orange = $matchingRow.OrangeID
$ipaddr = $matchingRow.ServerIP
```